# Extracting single data frame column from nested list

Tags: r, list, select, nested-lists

I have a nested list where the lowest level contains a data frame with multiple columns. Example below. I would like to extract from this a new list which contains only the first column of the data frame, "X1" in the example below, maintaining the rest of the list structure.

```
d1 <- tibble(X1 = 1:3, X2 = 0)
d2 <- tibble(X1 = 4:6, X2 = 0)
d3 <- tibble(X1 = 7:9, X2 = 0)

L <- list(
  list(d1, d1, d1),
  list(d2, d2, d2),
  list(d3, d3, d3)
)
```

Comment: Is the depth of the list fixed?  If so you can use `lapply(L, lapply, \`[[\`, 1L)` (or `lapply(L, lapply, \`[\`, 1L) ` to return a tibble).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would offer:

```
lapply(L, function(x) {
  lapply(x, function(x) x$X1) 
})
```

May I also give an advice not to use `L` for variable names as L is reserved for integer declaration in comparison to numeric. For instance `7L`.

Comment: Why do you think the parser could be confused by using `L` as an object name?

Comment: @Ritchie defintely the parser won't confuse this symbol. I was talking about general culture of coding. `L` for R programmers has its quite specific meaning.

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(purrr)

modify_tree(L, leaf = ~ .x[, 1])
```

`modify_tree` is recursive if you have the data frame at various depths. Otherwise, if it is always at the same depth you can do:

```r
modify_depth(L, 2, ~ .x[, 1])
```

Comment: Did no work in my real data, received this: "! no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')". Below from @asd-tm does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With `rrapply`. This works for any structure of nested lists:

```r
rrapply::rrapply(
  L,
  f = \(x) x[, 1],
  classes = "data.frame"
)
```

Structure of the output:

```r
# List of 3
# $ :List of 3
# ..$ : tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# .. ..$ X1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
# ..$ : tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# .. ..$ X1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
# ..$ : tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# .. ..$ X1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
# $ :List of 3
# ..$ : tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# .. ..$ X1: int [1:3] 4 5 6
# ..$ : tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# .. ..$ X1: int [1:3] 4 5 6
# ..$ : tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# .. ..$ X1: int [1:3] 4 5 6
# $ :List of 3
# ..$ : tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# .. ..$ X1: int [1:3] 7 8 9
# ..$ : tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# .. ..$ X1: int [1:3] 7 8 9
# ..$ : tibble [3 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# .. ..$ X1: int [1:3] 7 8 9
```